# Running event x from event y

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, events

(Newbie VB.NET question)

Here's the specific code behind my simple `winforms` that I don't fully understand:

```
Private Sub okButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles okButton.Click
    'do something
End Sub

Private Sub MainForm_Enter(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Enter
    okButton_Click(Me, e) '<=== argumanets must be wrong 
End Sub
```

What I'm trying to achieve:
If the user hits `Enter` when they have the `winforms` active then I'd like the `Click` event handler of the `okButton` to fire.

Obviously from the above my understanding of the arguments I need to supply to the `event` called `okButton_Click` is lacking; what are the correct arguments and why?

Comment: The [`Enter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.enter.aspx) event does not what you think it does.

Comment: @Mr.Steak ....what does it do? (further research seems to suggest I should be using the form property `Acceptbutton`?

Comment: If you have a simple dialog, using `Acceptbutton` and handling the `Close` event (where you simply check the if `DialogResult` if `OK` and then do your stuff) is a sensible approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you might use the [`AcceptButton`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.acceptbutton.aspx) property of the form. Just set it to the desired button and it should do the trick.
Note that there is also a [`CancelButton`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.cancelbutton.aspx) property.

Answering your event-question:
The `sender` argument marks the sender of the event. Mostly, this is the `Me` instance of the class. In my opinion, `Me` seems to be absolutely correct.
The `e` argument contains the `EventArgs` of the specific event. If you're not using this argument in your function body, the content of this variable doesn't matter. You could use `Nothing` or just route the `EventArgs` (that's what you've done).

Refering to your comment:
`EventArgs` is a base class for event-specific data. For example, if you're subscribing to a mouse event, `e`will be a [`MouseEventArgs`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.windows.forms.mouseeventargs.aspx). The `MouseEventArg` class offers you the mouse buttons that have been pressed and the coordinates of the pointer when the event was fired.

In your case, the events only have `EventArgs` which provide only basic information about the event. There does not seem to be special information about it.

Note: If you want to combine multiple events into one callback, you can make `e` of type `EventArgs` because every `e` should inherit from `EventArgs` following the Microsoft guidelines. Therefore, you can combine a Button-Click with a Mouse-Move into one callback because the signature of the delegates match.

A nicer way than just passing `Nothing` to the target Sub, is to combine two callbacks into one. You can do this in VB.NET using multiple `Handles` like this:

```
Private Sub SomeSub(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles okButton.Click, MyBase.Enter
    'this is getting called on a okButton.Click and MyBase.Enter
End Sub
```

(Scroll to the right to see the Handles)

Note that you don't need a second Sub which calls the first one. Everything is in one Sub.

Comment: ...do you have any further references to help me understand `e`? you say "The e argument contains the `EventArgs` of the specific event"

Comment: ok - thanks: I've marked as answer although I'm still slightly lost when it comes to events....the course I'm studying at the moment will hopefully help.

Comment: I just made another edit which shows multiple `Handles` sources.

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
Protected Overrides Function ProcessCmdKey(ByRef msg As System.Windows.Forms.Message, keyData As System.Windows.Forms.Keys) As Boolean
    If (keyData And Keys.KeyCode) = Keys.Enter Then
        okButton.PerformClick()
        Return True
    End If
    Return MyBase.ProcessCmdKey(msg, keyData)
End Function
```

You might need to exclude some controls in the check if you want to use enter key with other controls, ie:

```
If (keyData And Keys.KeyCode) = Keys.Enter AndAlso Not Textbox1.Focused Then
```